# Listview scroll programmatically android

Tags: android

I want to have a listview where the last item will be always visible.Everytime a new item is added,I want the listview to scroll to the last position from the current position.However when i use the code below:

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<>();

ValueEventListener valeuEventListener=new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.getValue()!=null){
            String s=snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if(s!=null){
                    listItems.add(s);
                    ListView listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);
                    ListAdapdet listAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_items, listItems);
                    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    listView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(listItems.getCount()-1));
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
};
```

Everytime a new item is added it starts scrolling from the top.How to solve this?

Comment: please include more detail in your post. show us your adapter and how you're setting it, maybe there's something wrong with your adapter

Comment: I request you to upload your main activity and adapter code here.

Comment: Please see the edited post.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you ask by using [`layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean))

> void setReverseLayout (boolean reverseLayout)
>
> Used to reverse item traversal and layout order. This behaves similar
> to the layout change for RTL views. When set to true, first item is
> laid out at the end of the UI, second item is laid out before it etc.
> For horizontal layouts, it depends on the layout direction. When set
> to true, If RecyclerView is LTR, than it will layout from RTL, if
> RecyclerView} is RTL, it will layout from LTR. If you are looking for
> the exact same behavior of setStackFromBottom(boolean), use
> setStackFromEnd(boolean)